# BigDecimal 2.0 is coming equal to BigDecimal 2.00

Tags: java, hashset, bigdecimal

I read the [Java doc of BigDecimal.equals() says](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html):

> Compares this BigDecimal with the specified Object for equality.
> Unlike compareTo, this method considers two BigDecimal objects equal
> only if they are equal in value and scale (**thus 2.0 is not equal to
> 2.00 when compared by this method**).

But when I am testing it then somehow I am getting unexpected result and `BigDecimal(2.0)` is coming equal to `BigDecimal(2.00)`. And I think for the same reason when I put `BigDecimal(2.0)` and `BigDecimal(2.00)` in `HashSet` then size comes as 1, while I was expecting size to be 2.Please see below code, and if someone could please point out if I am missing something?

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class CollectionTest {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new BigDecimal(2.0).compareTo(new BigDecimal(2.00))); // 0
        System.out.println(new BigDecimal(2.0).equals(new BigDecimal(2.00))); // true   -- ** UNEXPECTED **
        
        HashSet<BigDecimal> hashset = new HashSet<>();
        Set<BigDecimal> treeset = new TreeSet<>();
        
        hashset.add(new BigDecimal(2.0));
        hashset.add(new BigDecimal(2.00));
        
        treeset.add(new BigDecimal(2.0));
        treeset.add(new BigDecimal(2.00));
        
        System.out.println("hashset.size(): " + hashset.size());    // 1    -- ** UNEXPECTED **
        System.out.println("treeset.size(): " + treeset.size());    // 1
    }
}
```

Comment: Do not use the `new BigDecimal(double)` constructor. Use the one with the `String` argument instead. See the notes on https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal-double-

Answer (score 6):

At compile time the `double`s `2.0` and `2.00` are the same. You need a `String`. Like,

```
System.out.println(new BigDecimal(2.0).equals(new BigDecimal("2.00")));
```

Outputs

```
false
```

Your current code is the equivalent of

```
System.out.println(2 == 2.00);
```

Which is obviously `true`.

To expand on that last example, consider

```
BigDecimal a = new BigDecimal(2.0);
BigDecimal b = a.setScale(2);
System.out.printf("%s equals %s is %s%n", a, b, a.equals(b));
```

which should explain why your current code behaves as it does; because

```
2 equals 2.00 is false
```

Comment: Thanks, +1 but does it mean that in case of BigDecimal("2.00"), it tries to compare BigDecimal as String, while in case of BigDecimal(2.00) it tries to compare BigDecimal as a decimal primitve?

Comment: @pjj No, the double literals 2.0 and 2.00 **are** the same double value, so the `BigDecimal` values you create have the same value.

Comment: @Elliott: could you please clarify my above doubt so that I can accept it as answer. I know it might be silly but it is hanging in my mind.

Comment: @pjj There is an internal `scale` part in `BigDecimal`, which is checked in the `equals()` method. When you have the number `42` with the scale of `2`, that `BigDecimal` instance will be different (according to `equals()`) to a different `BigDecimal` instance with the same value `42`, but with the different scale `5`.